# Could not resolve dependency after installing jar

Tags: java, spring, maven

I installed my jars with:

```
install:install-file -Dfile="C:/Program Files/keydox/jkdx/codecs.jar" -DgroupId=keydoxWeb -DartifactId=keydoxWebCodec -Dversion=1.0
```

That worked fine and the jar also is in the .m2 repository.

But as I add them to the POM by:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.keydoxWeb</groupId>
    <artifactId>keydoxWebCodec</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I get the error message:

```
Failed to execute goal on project test: Could not resolve dependencies for 
project com.TestOne:test:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact 
com.keydoxWeb:keydoxWebCodec:jar:1.0 in spring-snapshot 
(http://repo.spring.io/snapshot)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you installed your `codecs.jar` you set the `-DgroupDId` to be `keydoxWeb`, in your pom.xml you're trying to get the artifact with groupid `com.keydoxWeb` which does not exist since it is installed without `com.`.

Comment: Oh thanks.  Sometimes it's the easiest mistakes we dont see. :D